# Excel Sheet 1 Checkbox check Sheet 2 Checkbox

Tags: excel, checkbox

When Sheet1.Check Box 21 is checked/unchecked I need Sheet2.CheckBox 17 to also check/uncheck. Is this VBA possible? (new to VBA) ...and thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA.. If you are using `Form Controls`, in the `Properties -> Cell link` them both to the same cell (Sheet1!A1 for instance) then they will check & uncheck together...

[image: Form Controls]

If you are using ActiveX, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Vincent De Smet. Linking both checkboxes to same cell worked.